# How to automatically unify and download the segmented videos of a website?

Tags: firefox, video, website, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

When I play the videos in a website, video downloading plugins in Firefox show that the playing video is broken into segments. Is there anyway to automatically unify the video segments and download the unified version at once?
I do not want to manually download each segment and attach them together offline.

Comment: Maybe the website is supported by youtube-dl?

Comment: Can you give an example of what website? And what video?

Comment: I wanted to download the videos of Wolfram Mathematica website. For example the Elementary introduction videos in Wolfram U.